# Cloudant and Php-on-Couch not working well due to continue

Tags: php, try-catch, cloudant

I believe Cloudant has recently changed some of their code.  Recently, if you do a storedoc operation, in a try/catch statement. Cloudant will return an 'error' to the framework:

**Uncaught exception 'couchException' with message 'Continue**

Of course you can handle it in the catch statement, but it should really be coming back as 'successful' in the Try statement of the PHP-on-Couch library.

Anyone come across this or know how to handle it?  The biggest issues is that you cannot grab the ID and Rev in the catch statement because it's coming up as an error:

```
                try { // does not return here, goes to catch
                    $response = $client->storeDoc($doc);
                    $response_json['status'] = 'success';
                    $response_json['id'] = $response->id;
                    $response_json['rev'] = $response->rev;
                } catch (Exception $e) { // even though the doc is successfully storing

                    // check for accepted BEG
                    $error = '';
                    $error = $e->getMessage();
                    $err_pos = strpos($error,"Accepted");
                    $err_pos_2 = strpos($error,"Continue");
                    if($err_pos !== false OR $err_pos_2 !== false){ // success

                        $response_json['status'] = 'success';
                        $response_json['id'] = $response->id; // returns null
                        $response_json['rev'] = $response->rev; // returns null

                    } else { // truely an error

                        $response_json['status'] = 'fail';
                        $response_json['message'] = $e->getMessage();
                        $response_json['code'] = $e->getCode();

                    }
                    // check for accepted END


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested in both CouchDB and Cloudant and the behavior is the same. This is what I believe is happening. When you create a new couchDocument:

```
$doc = new couchDocument($client);
```

By default the document is set to autocommit. You can see this in couchDocument.php:

```
function __construct(couchClient $client) {
    $this->__couch_data = new stdClass();
    $this->__couch_data->client = $client;
    $this->__couch_data->fields = new stdClass();
    $this->__couch_data->autocommit = true;
}
```

As soon as you set a property on the document:

```
$doc->set( array('name'=>'Smith','firstname'=>'John') );
```

`storeDoc` is immediately called. You are then trying to call `storeDoc` a second time and couchDB returns an error.

There are 2 ways to fix this:

1. Turn off autocommit:

   ```
   $doc = new couchDocument($client);
   $doc->setAutocommit(false);
   $doc->set( array('name'=>'Smith','firstname'=>'John') );
   try {
       $response = $client->storeDoc($doc);
       $response_json['status'] = 'success';
       $response_json['id'] = $response->id;
       $response_json['rev'] = $response->rev;
   ```
2. Keep autocommit on and get the id and rev from the `$doc` after you set a property:

   ```
   $doc = new couchDocument($client);
   try {
       $doc->set( array('name'=>'Smith','firstname'=>'John') );
       $response_json['status'] = 'success';
       $response_json['id'] = $doc->_id;
       $response_json['rev'] = $doc->_rev;
   ```

Comment: I tried both ways, Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Method setAutocommit does not exist' and similar with $doc->set   Everything worked fine probably a few weeks to a month ago or so.

Comment: Is this the library you are using? https://github.com/dready92/PHP-on-Couch. I just downloaded the php files when I answered this question and they worked for me.

Comment: Ahh forgive me... I need to be using' couch_document class'... will test more later.  Thank you for the quick reply and solutions.